# how to create read-only user in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have tried below method for creating read only user.

```
Steps
*********
create user backup with password 'backup123';
grant connect on database "uday" to backup;
grant select on all tables in schema public to backup;
grant select on all tables in uday public to backup;
```

but the user is able to write which is not correct.
I have tried some other methods also but in vain.

The read only user which is created can only select and should not delete / create / update etc on the tables. 
Kindly some one can reply for this. I have spend more time on this but not able to get the appropriate solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default users have the right to create tables in the `public` schema. First, run:

```
revoke all on schema public from backup;
```

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PUBLIC).